# python pandas how to get multiple columns of grouped result

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe(named df) as follows:

```
id, a,  b,  c
1, 10, 10, 10
1, 20, 20, 20
2, 10, 10, 10
2, 20, 20, 20
3, 10, 10, 10
3, 20, 20, 20
```

I need to get result using multiple columns within each group.

```
grouped = df.groupby('id')
grouped['a','b','c'].apply(lambda x,y,z:x*y+z)
```

But, the second line has error:

```
KeyError: ('a', 'b', 'c').
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt raises a `KeyError` because it's not able to resolve this into a column selection like you normally think it does, whilst `df.groupby('id')['a'].head()` works, `df.groupby('id')['a','b'].head()` will also raise a `KeyError`. To select the columns of interest you need to supply a list of the columns of interest to the subsript operator like so:

```
In [163]:

df.groupby('id')[['a','b','c']].apply(lambda x: x['a']*x['b']*x['c'])
Out[163]:
id   
1   0    1000
    1    8000
2   2    1000
    3    8000
3   4    1000
    5    8000
dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

To further illuminate why it would normally seem sensible to perform column selection the way you did, if we refer to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby), we see that

```
df.groupby('id')['a']
```

is syntactic sugar for the more verbose:

```
df['a'].groupby('id')
```

So if we try this:

```
df['a','b']
```

this will also raise a `KeyError`, whilst this does not:

```
df[['a','b']]
```

Comment: Had the same solution in mind but I am still getting `KeyError: "Columns not found: 'a', 'c', 'b'"`. pandas 0.15.2

Comment: @Primer have you parsed the OP's input data correctly? Check if your column selection matches the output from `df.columns`, I'm on `0.16.0` but that shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Thanks, bloody spaces were spoiling it. It works indeed.

Comment: I've added an explanation of the error, it becomes clearer why it fails, although there was nothing wrong with your thought process.